# Make method asynchronius in ajax success section

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax, syncfusion

I have the following ajax script.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "DELETE",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function (data) {
    var grid = $('#rolesgrid').ejGrid("instance");
    grid.refreshContent();
    $('#rolesgrid_delete').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    renameConditionType(grid);     
  },
  error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    showDialogMessage('Page error', errorThrown, 'danger');
  }  
});
```

When I make request by calling function `grid.refreshContent()`. The next function `renameConditionType(grid)` is called. This second change context of specific column.

When request from function `grid.refreshContent()` is finished. It overwrites the result of function `renameConditionType(grid)`.

How to make in order to wait when request from function `grid.refreshContent()`. I use syncfusion javascript grid.

Comment: It seems like the `refreshContent()` is async. Does it accept a callback argument to the function? Do you have a link to their documentation

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can't OP just use promises in this case?

Comment: Not without knowing when the `refreshContent()` call completes. If the library is of any worth it should either allow you to use callbacks or raise events when the content loading is finalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use  refreshContent method the actionComplete event of ejGrid will be triggered. In this event you can check the requestType as refresh using the arguments to achieve your requirement.

Please refer the below documentation for the details of the actionComplete event and refreshContent method.

https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejgrid#events:actioncomplete

https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejgrid#methods:refreshcontent

If you still face any complexities please get back to me with the following details.

1. In the renameconditiontype() function are you changing the column name or the dataSource of the column.
2. Do you need the result of the renameconditiontype() method to be maintained after gridRefreshContent() method is called.
3. Share the grid code example.